# How to concatenate strings to provide as input when calling the term command in neovim

Tags: python, vim, neovim

I have the following  example:

```
autocmd FileType python nnoremap <buffer> <leader>c :let python_file=expand('%:p')<CR>:term 'python ' . python_file<CR>
```

This is an example script for running python code, however whenever I try to use this keybinding in a python file I get the following error:

```
''python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

What seems to be happening is that the term command may not be concatenating the strings properly (`'python ' . python_file`) which I am providing it as a command.

Is there a way I can fix this?

Please note that this is just a simplified example of something which I am trying to do please do not suggest a solution such as `:term python expand('%:p')` which I know will work for most common cases but it will not work in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:terminal` expects a string, not an expression. You will have to use `:help :execute` to put your command together:

```
nnoremap <key> :let python_file=expand('%:p')<CR>:execute 'term python ' .. python_file<CR>
```

---

> (Please note that this is just a simplified example of something which I am trying to do please do not suggest a solution such as `:term python expand('%:p')` which I know will work for most common cases but it will not work in my case)

Well, it can be simplified even further:

```
autocmd FileType python nnoremap <buffer> <leader>c :term python %:p<CR>
```

Be smart when asking questions. The mapping as you posted it makes no sense so it is pretty legitimate for answerers to focus on the example *you* gave them and to suggest things based on the examples you submitted: the XY problem is a real problem in these parts.

Case in point, your problem could be stated in much simple terms that wouldn't attract unwanted attention to your contrived mapping:

> I have a file path in variable `...` but I can't make `:term` use it. I have tried `...` and `...` but nothing worked. What did I do wrong?

To which there can only be one answer, that doesn't assume anything about your intent.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will try to write my questions in a more clear and concise way next time.